# Serialize groups in groupby and add a column for a group number

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a dataframe:

```
    ml  room    box_num
0   1526    106     11
3   1608    106     9
9   1601    106     8
13  1603    106     8
17  1604    106     8
22  1558    106     5
24  1556    106     2
28  1557    106     2
32  1534    009     19
39  1552    009     104
43  1551    009     105
49  1550    009     102
57  1539    009     23
65  1546    009     23
73  1560    009     28
```

I need to add a group number for unique values of `[room, box_num]`, so that it will look like this:

```
    ml  room    box_num  group_num
0   1526    106     11   0
3   1608    106     9    1
9   1601    106     8    2
13  1603    106     8    2
17  1604    106     8    2
22  1558    106     5    3
24  1556    106     2    4
28  1557    106     2    4
32  1534    009     19   5
39  1552    009     104  6
43  1551    009     105  7
49  1550    009     102  8
57  1539    009     23   9
65  1546    009     23   9
73  1560    009     28   10
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with both columns joined with `-` and converted to strings, because need combination values of both columns:

```
df['group_num'] = pd.factorize(df['room'].astype(str) + '-' + df['box_num'].astype(str))[0]
```

Or convert both columns to `list of tuple`s by `map`:

```
df['group_num'] = pd.factorize(list(map(tuple, df[['room','box_num']].values)))[0]
```

---

```
print (df)
      ml  room  box_num  group_num
0   1526   106       11          0
3   1608   106        9          1
9   1601   106        8          2
13  1603   106        8          2
17  1604   106        8          2
22  1558   106        5          3
24  1556   106        2          4
28  1557   106        2          4
32  1534     9       19          5
39  1552     9      104          6
43  1551     9      105          7
49  1550     9      102          8
57  1539     9       23          9
65  1546     9       23          9
73  1560     9       28         10
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['room'].astype(str) + '-' + df['box_num'].astype(str))
0     106-11
3      106-9
9      106-8
13     106-8
17     106-8
22     106-5
24     106-2
28     106-2
32      9-19
39     9-104
43     9-105
49     9-102
57      9-23
65      9-23
73      9-28
dtype: object

print (list(map(tuple, df[['room','box_num']].values)))
[(106, 11), (106, 9), (106, 8), (106, 8), (106, 8), (106, 5), 
 (106, 2), (106, 2), (9, 19), (9, 104), (9, 105), (9, 102), (9, 23), (9, 23), (9, 28)]
```